# Relacionar disciplinas e estudantes de um sistema de pré-matrícula

Tags: java, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Estou fazendo um sistema de pré-matrícula, e me deparei com um problema que me incomoda um pouco:
[image: Diagrama de classes]

Como vocês podem ver na imagem, `Curso` tem `Disciplinas` e `Estudantes`, só que cada estudante precisa saber em quais `Disciplinas` ele está matriculado, e cada `Disciplina` precisa saber quais `Estudantes` estão matriculados nela.

Eu já pensei em `Estudante` ter uma lista de `Disciplina` ou `Disciplina` ter uma lista de `Estudante`, e também os dois. O grande problema é que das formas que eu consegui pensar ficaram um pouco acopladas.

Alguém poderia dar uma sugestão do que eu posso fazer, ou um `Design Pattern` que resolve isso?

Comment: acredito que relacionamento N para N entre estudante e disciplina resolveria seu caso

Answer (score 2):

Poderia ser criada uma classe chamada `Turma`, formado por um atributo `Disciplina` e por uma lista de `Estudantes`. O `Curso` teria uma lista de `Turmas`.

Para saber em quais `Disciplinas` o `Estudante` está matriculado, usaria um método em `Curso` que acessa a lista de `Turmas` e para cada `Turma` iria acessar o método que verifica se o `Estudante` está presente no mesmo.

A mesma lógica poderia ser usado para `Disciplina` saber quais `Estudantes` estão matriculados.